# "Disease Spread" challenge

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, mathematics

Right now I'm solving [this problem](http://www.codewars.com/kata/disease-spread/train/java) on codewars.com. I'm not sure about how to optimise the code further. Or is my algorithm inefficient? If it's an algorithmic issue, could someone help me how to go about it?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Epidem {

    public static int epidemic(int tm, int n, int s0, int i0, double b, double a) {
        // your code
     double dt = tm/n;
     double s1,i1,r,j;
     r=0;j=0;

     while(j<=tm)
      {
      s1 = s0 - dt*b*s0*i0;
      i1 = i0 + dt*(b*s0*i0 - a*i0);
      r = r + dt * i0 * a;
      s0 = (int) s1;
      i0 = (int) i1;
      j+=dt;
      }

     return (int) i0;

    }
}
```

It fails in the following cases:

```
int tm = 18 ;int n = 432 ;int s0 = 1004 ;int i0 = 1 ;double b = 0.00209 ;double a = 0.51;

    tm = 12 ;n = 288 ;s0 = 1007 ;i0 = 2 ;b = 0.00206 ;a = 0.45;

    tm = 13 ;n = 312 ;s0 = 999 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00221 ;a = 0.55;

    tm = 24 ;n = 576 ;s0 = 1005 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00216 ;a = 0.45;

    tm = 24 ;n = 576 ;s0 = 982 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00214 ;a = 0.44;

    tm = 20 ;n = 480 ;s0 = 1000 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00199 ;a = 0.53;

    tm = 28 ;n = 672 ;s0 = 980 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00198 ;a = 0.44;

    tm = 14 ;n = 336 ;s0 = 996 ;i0 = 2 ;b = 0.00206 ;a = 0.41;

    tm = 13 ;n = 312 ;s0 = 993 ;i0 = 2 ;b = 0.0021 ;a = 0.51;

    tm = 28 ;n = 672 ;s0 = 999 ;i0 = 1 ;b = 0.00197 ;a = 0.55;
```

Comment: Please add the problem description into your question. What do you mean with **fails** ?

Comment: It needs to run in less than 20000ms

Comment: @ArvindPrakash please add the problem description, not just a link. Links can rot.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered by @Thomasky:

```
double dt = ((double)tm) / n;
```

There are some common subexpressions, multiplications, you need to do only once. like `b*(s0*i0)` (integer multiplication first).

The while loop would better go as (more precise, faster):

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    double bsi = dt*b*(s0*i0);
    double ai = dt*a*i0
    s0 -= (int) -bsi;
    i0 += (int) (bsi - ai);
    //r += ai; // As unused?
}
```

Variables can (and should) be declared as locally as possible, a declaration in a loop does not do more work as outside; there is just one slot reserved on the function stack.

The cast of `(int)` does no rounding.
As you might imagine, `n*dt` increases the approximation error in `dt` by n-fold. However more precision, a correction, would cost time.

Maybe using doubles, say `double s1 = s0; double i1 = i0;` instead of `s0` and `i0` would give a better solution. No idea.

And finally this task is solvable with a bit of math.

Answer (score 1):

Your error might be due to integer division.

On the following line

```
double dt = tm/n;
```

you'll perform integer division since both `tm` and `n` are `int`.
Whenever `n > tm`, the result will be rounded down to 0.